# Android + (Java Time or ThirteenTenABP) ZonedDateTime.of yields unexpected result

Tags: android, java-8, timezone, java-time

#### Context

- This is an Android App running on API 29 (with a Min of 23).
- I'm using [ThirteenTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

#### Issue

I'm simply debugging some code and I do the following:

```
val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(
                          LocalDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 15, 15, 0),
                          ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

This prints (`toString()` as:

`1900-01-01T15:15+00:19:32[Europe/Amsterdam]`

#### Expected

I would have expected to see `1900-01-01T15:15+02:00:00[Europe/Amsterdam]` or similar.

The current Offset from UTC in Amsterdam is +2 due to daylight savings. Yet, I see these 19 minutes and 32 seconds.

This means that if I convert that Zoned date time to UTC using something like:

`val utcZoned = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`

I get (consistently with the error above):

`1900-01-01T14:55:28Z`

So it's 14:55:28 or what is equivalent to the time 15:15 (3:15 pm) minus 19 minutes and thirty-two seconds.

Am I missing something here?

I'm running this on an Emulator. `ZoneId.getSystemDefault()` also returns the same ZoneId + Offset. I started hardcoding Amsterdam to see if I could spot a difference.

Another way to see this, is simply by doing:

```
ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(1900,01,01,15,15,0), ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")).offset
```

The result is a `ZoneOffset`

And consistently with the ninteen minutes above:

The offset is: `+00:19:32`

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Did I try `java.time.*`?

Yes, I removed ThirteenTenABP, and replaced all imports to `java.time.*` and ran this on an Android O (8.x) to see if the native Java8 time classes would yield a similar result and the answer is: yes.

The offsets come from the offset rules:

[image: Amsterdam ZoneOffset Rules]

But why those numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that's correct, Amsterdam's timezone [used to be](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/netherlands/amsterdam?year=1909) based off of the time in [Westerkerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westerkerk).

> The reason for the specific offset of +0h 19m 32.13s was that the time zone was centered on the mean solar time of the Westertoren (4° 53' 01.95" E Longitude), the tower of the Westerkerk church in Amsterdam.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B00:20

Bare in mind the [docs for `ZonedDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-) say

> The local date-time is then resolved to a single instant on the time-line

So it will give you back a time using the timezone that was in use at that instant in time, not the current timezone in use in the Netherlands.

Comment: Oh my gosh... it never occurred to me to check if this *was a thing*... I assumed the number was "random". Thanks! And regarding your update, yes, I'd expect that the returned datetime respected the offset "at the time".

Comment: I knew time code was messy, but I'd never heard of such an irregular time offset before either!

Comment: If the date-time returned weren't resolved in use at the _time_ (no pun intended) one would start wondering why do we use all these abstractions to begin with, right? :)))